# Desktop displaying the titles of my minimized windows

Tags: macos, keyboard

I am using a MacBook Air, OS X Yosemite, v 10.10.1

Just recently I have started seeing the titles of my minimized windows listed on my desktop.  The problem is the text bleeds through to other opened windows where I am trying to work.  The titles are not links and I can't select them in any way or move them around.

I have looked on the System Preferences and can't find anything that relates.  Assume I did some kind of keyboard shortcut.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It's not something I've heard of. Do you have a picture? Post to somewhere like imgur, flickr etc & link here; someone with the necessary rep can inline it for you.

Answer (score 1):

The title should only appear when you hover your mouse over a minimized window. There is no setting to change this.

Try running these two commands in Terminal:

```
killall -KILL Finder
killall -KILL Dock
```

This will cause the Finder and Dock to relaunch, which often fixes graphical anomalies.

(Also suggest updating to 10.10.3 to ensure you are benefitting from any bugs fixed in the last two updates.)